# Match keyword (Full Text Search ) not working with SQLite3 C API

Tags: android, c, sqlite, fts3

I am using [SQLite3 C API](http://www.sqlite.org/capi3ref.html) in an Android App. I want to implement Full Text Search in a Table.

**Created a Virtual Table in it :**

```
create VIRTUAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS call_record USING fts3(_id  int, call_id text not null, caller text not null, recipient text not null, record_type  text not null, start_time text not null, end_time text not null, UNIQUE(call_id) PRIMARY KEY(_id));
```

**Inserted Few Records in it :**

```
INSERT INTO call_record (call_id, caller, recipient, record_type, start_time, end_time) VAlUES (123, 'John', 'Jane', 0, 12345, 12344);

INSERT INTO call_record (call_id, caller, recipient, record_type, start_time, end_time) VAlUES (456, 'Jane', 'Mike', 0, 12345, 12344);

INSERT INTO call_record (call_id, caller, recipient, record_type, start_time, end_time) VAlUES (789, 'Ram', 'Shyam', 0, 12345, 12344);
```

**Getting Records Correctly :**

```
Select * from Call_record;
```

**Getting Records Correctly :**

```
Select * from Call_record where caller LIKE 'j%';
```

**But Match Keyword not giving any Results :**

```
SELECT call_id, caller, recipient, start_time, end_time FROM call_record WHERE caller MATCH 'j*';
```

To verify my Queries and Approach, I installed [DB Browser for SQLite](http://sqlitebrowser.org/) and performed same operations and getting results correctly using Match.

When I read more about [SQLite3 C API](http://www.sqlite.org/capi3ref.html), it's mentioned there that sqlite3_db_config should be called with SQLITE_DBCONFIG_ENABLE_FTS3_TOKENIZER, so I did the exact thing but nothing chaged :

```
    rc = sqlite3_db_config(db, SQLITE_DBCONFIG_ENABLE_FTS3_TOKENIZER, 1, NULL);
    if (rc) {
        LOGE("Can'tconfigure SQLite FTS3: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        return -1;
    }
```

Any help / suggestion would be highly appreciated.

**Note** : The mentioned queries are actual queries copied from console logs.

Comment: Does using `LIKE` instead of `MATCH` work instead?

Comment: @Chris : Yep LIKE works but for FTS, I must use MATCH.